# One question about the mathematical analysis

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

There is such a question. Let $\phi(t)$ be a positive continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ and $f(t,x)$ be a continuous function of two variables such that $|f(t,x)|\le\phi(t)|x|$. Suppose $\int_0^\infty\phi(t)dt<\infty$. Show that if the function $y$ satisfies the inequality 
$$|y(t)|\le\int_0^t|f(s,y(s))|ds$$
for all $t\in[0,\infty)$, then $y(t)\equiv0$.

Actually, I have first proved that $\phi(t)$ is bounded. And use this rusult to try to prove $y(t)$ and continuous. However, it seems that something made me stuck. Hope you can give some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t)=\int_0^t|f(s,y(s))|ds$. Then $|y(t)|\le g(t)$ and
$$
\dot g(t)=|f(s,y(s))|\leϕ(t)|y(t)|\le ϕ(t) g(t)
$$
which can be solved via separation or integrating factor to get
$$
g(t)\le \exp\left(\int_0^t\phi(s)ds\right)g(0)=0.
$$
As $0\le |y(t)|\le g(t)$, this leaves not much room for the values of $y$.

See also Grönwall lemma.